# PHP Mongodb - POST array insert

Tags: php, mongodb, object, insert

I am trying to convert post data into a format that would allow me to pass it right into my collection. For example: When I print_r on the $_POST I get this form data:

```
Array
(
    [Name] => Steve
    [Email] => Steve@mail.com
    [submit] => Submit
)
```

I am wondering how i can convert this to an acceptable object to insert into mongodb collection using php similar to:

```
$Record = array(
    'Name' => 'Steve',
    'Email' => 'Steve@mail.com',
    'submit' => 'Submit'
);
$Collection->insert($Record);
```

I am thinking a loop of the above array with some additional formatting but I can't seem to figure it out.  I have also tried json_encode but keep getting the same error "Call to a member function insert() on a **non-object** in..." saying that its not a proper object.  Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to encode anything, it's just PHP native and expects an array. Let the driver do the work for you:

```
$Collection->insert( $_POST );
```

As it is the two should be equivalant:

```
$rec = array(
  'Name' => 'Steve',
  'Email' => 'Steve@mail.com',
  'submit' => 'Submit'
);

print_r ($rec);
```

Comment: I have tried that but getting the error "Call to a member function insert() on a non-object in..."

Comment: @user982853 are you doing it exactly like above or are you calling json_encode?

Comment: Exactly as you posted.

Comment: It seems there was something wrong with my include.  I had the mongo connection in an include/class and once i took it out of the class and just put it in the same file it all works fine. I will have to play with my include/class to see what i did wrong.  Thanks.